# Can I know which network a deployment script is running on?

Tags: hardhat

When running a deployment script on Hardhat with a specified network

```
npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.ts  --network <network-name>
```

I want to get the `<network-name>` variable in the script so I could set different parameters for different chains.
Is there a way to get that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

within your deploy script use:

```js
ethers.provider.network
```

this will show you the chainId, which should be unique for every network, as well as the network name

or alternatively read the runtime arguments

```js
hre.hardhatArguments
```

Comment: That worked

const hre = require("hardhat");
const chain = hre.hardhatArguments.network;